# Extend golang struct

Tags: go, struct, embedding

I try to extend the base struct, like this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    A bool
    C bool
}

type B struct {
    A
    B bool
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    a := A{
        A: false,
        C: false,
    }

    b := B{
        a,
        true,
    }

    fmt.Print(b)
}
```

But it creates inherit struct. The output of this code is: `{{false false} true}`

But I would like to get `{false false true}`

Is it possible?

Comment: "But I would like to get" --- it's an XY problem. Do you really want just to print it that way only, or there is some other reason you didn't reveal?

Comment: "Is it possible?" No. Embedding is composition, not inheritance. You will fail mimicking inheritance.

Comment: Is `fmt.Print(b)` what you really want or are you just using it for testing? If you want to encode to JSON using `encoding/json`, `b` marshals with all top level keys `{"A":false,"C":false,"B":true}`. See: https://play.golang.org/p/S3pS1PU_0WY .

Comment: @zerkms I would like to get struct like ```{
 A bool
 B bool
 C bool
}```

Comment: @SergeyGorbunov what _actual_ problem do you have with nesting?

Comment: @zerkms I need to extend the struct to add some additional fields and send it via rmq. I can't use existed struct, because  it is used in db model

Answer (score 4):

There is no extension in the "classical" OOP sense, embedding a type in a struct will **not** add fields of the embedded struct but add a **single field** with a type being the embedded type, which can be referred to by the unqualified type name: `b.A`.

If you just want so that it gets printed like you want, you may implement the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Stringer) interface:

```
func (b B) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{%t %t %t}", b.A.A, b.C, b.B)
}
```

Then output would be like (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eTe9TVuZMmf)):

```
{false false true}
```

But that's the end of it.